Find the solution of $y^4 + y^2 - 2y + 6 = 0$
Given the equation
$y^4 + y^2 - 2y + 6 = 0$
then, $p = 1, q = -2$, and $r = 6$
and the resolvent equation is:
$t^3 - t^2 - 24t + 20  = 0$
which has $t = 5$ as the solution, then the equation
$(y^2 + \frac{t}{2})^2 = (t - p)y^2 - qy + (\frac{t^2}{4} - r)$
will become
$(y^2 + \frac{5}{2})^2 = (5 - 1)y^2 - (-2)y + (\frac{5^2}{4} - 6)$
$(y^2 + \frac{5}{2})^2 = 4y^2 + 2y + \frac{1}{4} = (2y + \frac{1}{2})^2$
and so on ...
However, I'm curious why we only take the $t = 5$? and not taking the other root also?

$y^4+y^2-2y+6=(y^2-2y+2)(y^2+2y+3)$

i'm sorry, but can you explain more? I have to solve this not with factorization way


Sophie Germain Identity :
$a^4 + 4b^4 = (a^2 + 2b^2)^2 - 4a^2b^2 = (a^2 - 2ab + 2b^2)(a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2)$

$$y^4 + y^2 -2y + 6 = 0$$
$$ => y^4 + 4(1)^4 + y^2 - 2y + 2 = 0$$
$$ => (y^2 - 2y + 2)(y^2 + 2y + 2) + y^2 - 2y + 2 = 0 $$[using the above identity]
$$ => (y^2 - 2y + 2)(y^2 + 2y + 3) = 0$$
which is simply two quadratics , solving this we get $y = 1 ± i, -1 ± √2i$

I feel this identity is very useful for biquadratics , so keep this identity in mind whenever encountering them

Also it's not always feasible to go for Ferrari 's method of nothing works then only go for it
